Select Power BI Pro home region, different from Office 365 region
We already have an Office 365 tenant with a fixed home region in europe. Now we plan to setup Power BI with only Power BI Pro licenses, but there is a data governance related prerequisite, that all Power BI cloud data has to be stored outside of europe.
Is it possible, during Power BI setup process, to select an other region for only the Power BI data? I know migration is possible with a Premium license and Multi-Geo, but we don't have that.

No it will be the same tenant as the M365 one. You would have to open an MS support ticket to move everything to an updated 'home' tenant

@Jon I've read about that migration option, and that it could take several months to finish it. Do you know if it would also cause additional costs?
